# how to make pipe filter date range when using datetimepicker theme

Tags: javascript, angular, pipe, datetimepicker

I have a theme HTML using DateTime picker and a file HTML use it.

How to make a pipe filter date range when choosing a date in DateTime picker?

Comment: Why do you want to use pipes?

Comment: I just know use pipe to make the filter in angular 2. You can give me other resolves you know. thanks

Comment: who answer my question? pls